# Calculate obstacle accountability area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, polygon-creation

Still being new to the whole GIS world, I am trying to calculate a regulatory takeoff obstacle accountability area for a given runway. For my case, this is defined as an area as follows. At the start of the extended runway centerline it is 90m wide both sides, then widens by an 8th of every distance unit along that centerline up to a width of 900m, after which it is constant at 900m wide either side. Sketch attached (known line - green; to be calculated - magenta).

[image: obstacle accountability area]

I think what I want is a polygon with the above characteristics. I do have this in a kml file; however I wonder whether it would be possible to calculate this directly in QGIS, if I have the start point and extended centerline as vector. Can anyone help?

All the best

Comment: Have you solved this question yet? If you want a take off surface for a specific runway, I've created a program that does just that. I can send you a kml of the surface. You've provided in ur question the lateral dimensions but not vertical values (i.e. Slope). Also I would need the runway threshold coordinates. I think we can pm each other if needed...

Comment: I've got an Excel VB script that does exactly that. What I use QGIS for is extracting DEM terrain heights under the flight path. Currently, the process requires quite a few manual touches; however I feel that most of it should be doable in QGIS itself. Ideally, I would like to load the DEM and the flight path, then QGIS should calculate the obstacle accountability area, sample the DEM along the flight path inside the area to find the highest DEM elevation for each point on the track, and then export this in a 2D table. I am still very new to QGIS though and don't really know how to start.